# How to find and replace texts between specified tags in a word document using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, docx, win32com, python-docx

I would like to open Word and keep the original formatting of the Word document and only apply bold to the text between the start and end tags using python.

I have a code that only bolds the last found text in a single paragraph but I need to bold all findings in each paragraph. The code that I am using is below

```
import docx

# Open the Word document

doc = docx.Document('sample1.docx')

# Define the starting and end tags

start_tag = '\<strong\>'
end_tag = '\</strong\>'

# Loop through all paragraphs in the document

for para in doc.paragraphs:
\# Get the text of the paragraph
text = para.text

    # Find all occurrences of text surrounded by starting and end tags
    start_index = 0
    while True:
        start_index = text.find(start_tag, start_index)
        print(start_index)
        if start_index == -1:
            break
        end_index = text.find(end_tag, start_index + len(start_tag))
        if end_index == -1:
            break
        
        # Get the text between the starting and end tags
        bold_text = text[start_index + len(start_tag):end_index]
        
        # Replace the text in the paragraph with its bolded value
        para.clear()
        para.add_run(text[:start_index])
        para.add_run(text[start_index + len(start_tag):end_index]).bold = True
        para.add_run(text[end_index + len(end_tag):])
        
        # Update the start index for the next search
        start_index = end_index + len(end_tag)
        # print(start_index)

# Save the modified document

doc.save('sample_modified.docx')
```

The result taken from the word file is below:

```
<strong>NOTE:</strong> You <strong>could</strong> obviously do the same <strong>with</strong> ANY style that has a one-to-one mapping from.
```

This code only makes the last found text which is 'has' as bold and extracts the tags. However, I need to perform the same operation for each findings. Can you help me about this issue please?

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to break down the text and then reconstruct bolding those sections within the tags;
**Update**
Updated code for additional formatting as described in the comments.

```
import docx
import re


# Open the Word document
doc = docx.Document('sample.docx')

tags_list = ['strong', 'em', 'strong em']

for para in doc.paragraphs:
    para_text = para.text
    if para_text == '':
        continue

    ### Combine the strong em into a single tag
    text = para_text.replace('<strong><em>', '<strong em>')
    text = text.replace('</em></strong>', '</strong em>')

    ### Create a new paragraph
    newPara = para.insert_paragraph_before()

    ### Remove the existing so we don't have duplicates
    para.clear()

    ### Get all indexex for all tags
    indexes = []
    pattern = '<('
    for item in tags_list:
        pattern += f"{item}|"
    pattern = pattern[:-1] + r")>[^<]*</\1>"

    for match in re.finditer(pattern, text, re.DOTALL):
        indexes += match.regs[0]

    ### Split text into its parts
    parts = [text[i:j] for i, j in zip(indexes, indexes[1:] + [None])]
    if indexes[0] != 0:
        parts.insert(0, text[:indexes[0]])

    ### Recombine text applying necessary formatting
    for part in parts:
        tag = re.findall('<[^<]+?>', part)[0] if part[0] == '<' else None
        if tag:
            strip_text = re.sub('<[^<]+?>', '', part)
            run = newPara.add_run(strip_text)
            if "<strong" in tag:
                run.bold = True
            if "em>" in tag:
                run.italic = True
        else:
            newPara.add_run(part.replace('\n', ''))

### Remove added empty paragraphs 
for para in doc.paragraphs:
    if len(para.text) == 0:
        p = para._element
        p.getparent().remove(p)
        p._p = p._element = None
    
doc.save('sample_modified.docx')
```

Third sample data [before and after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4AKkj.png)

Comment: I appreciate your answer, it was beneficial. Actually, I'm having some problems while integrating this code. The problem is that I have a document that contains texts that are needed to be bold, italic, and both italic and bold. These 3 types have 3 different tags which are <strong>, <em>, and <strong><em>. I am able to change the fonts for bold and both bold and italic parts but I couldn't manage to change the italic text parts.

Comment: Examples of paragraphs are the following. `A <strong>gyroscope</strong> is a device used for <em>measuring or maintaining</em> orientation and angular velocity. 
It is a spinning <strong><em>wheel or disc</em></strong> in which the axis of rotation (spin axis) is free to assume any orientation by itself. When rotating, <em>the orientation of this axis is unaffected by tilting or rotation of the mounting</em>, according to the conservation of angular momentum.`

Comment: As a note, when there was text at the beginning of the sentence, the font of which would remain fixed, it did not add that text to the word. For this reason, I added 0 as the initial value to the arrays without the beginning of the array 0, and the problem was solved. Another issue is that for multiple paragraphs that contain these tags, the next paragraph is written with one empty space that should be removed to protect the formatting.

Comment: Actually, I've solved all the issues. there is only one problem left which is inserting 1 empty line after processed paragraphs. It automatically inserts 1 empty line that I cannot remove. How could I remove the added lines from the document?

Comment: The problem is not only an empty paragraph added at the end of the doc. Whenever a paragraph is processed for bold, italic, or both operations, it adds an extra blank line after paragraphs. I will share the code that I've improved in terms of different tags but the added blank line problem is still valid. If you have another solution idea related to the problem, I would be happy to listen. By the way, thanks for the effort.

Comment: The `newPara.add_run` does it, I don't think it can be avoided. You might need to run another loop to check and remove any empty paragraphs after modifying since any new empty paragraphs wont be in the intial loop. You can change the code at the end to be a loop on `doc.paragraphs` and delete any that are empty.

Comment: Okay, I will look into your suggestions and will try to find a solution to that. Thanks again for reaching out to my question.

Comment: I made one more update to the code for the loop and delete on empty paragraphs before saving. I ran this code with your latest three paragraph example. You can see the before and after in the attached screen shot, the extra lines are not present.

Comment: Yes @moken, I found and implement the piece of code that you added however the problem with that part is that it deletes all the empty lines but if there is a figure after the empty line, it also deletes the figure itself. I'm looking for a solution to that for now since my document will include figures and tables.

Answer (score 0):

The final version of the code that I improved based on **moken**'s responses is written below. The empty lines in the Word document are removed using Python win32com library and the problem is solved.

```
import docx
import re
import numpy as np
import inspect, os
import win32com.client as win32
import win32com.client

def split_tagged_sections(text, start_tag, end_tag):
    
    if '<strong>' not in text:
        # Split the text by start and end tags
        segments = re.split(f'({start_tag}|{end_tag})', text)

        # Initialize the result array and a variable to track opened tags
        result = []
        opened_tags = 0

        # Iterate through the segments
        for segment in segments:
            if not segment:
                continue

            # If we encounter a start tag, increase the count of opened_tags
            if segment == start_tag:
                opened_tags += 1
                if opened_tags == 1:
                    result.append(start_tag)
                else:
                    result[-1] += start_tag

            # If we encounter an end tag, decrease the count of opened_tags
            elif segment == end_tag:
                opened_tags -= 1
                result[-1] += end_tag

            # If we're inside a tagged section, append the segment to the last opened tag
            elif opened_tags > 0:
                result[-1] += segment

            # Otherwise, simply append the segment to the result array
            else:
                result.append(segment)
           
    elif '<strong>' in text:
        start_tag_b = '<strong>'
        end_tag_b = '</strong>'
        # Split the text by start and end tags
        segments = re.split(f'({start_tag_b}|{end_tag_b})', text)

        # Initialize the result array and a variable to track opened tags
        result = []
        opened_tags = 0

        # Iterate through the segments
        for segment in segments:
            if not segment:
                continue

            # If we encounter a start tag, increase the count of opened_tags
            if segment == start_tag_b:
                opened_tags += 1
                if opened_tags == 1:
                    result.append(start_tag_b)
                else:
                    result[-1] += start_tag_b

            # If we encounter an end tag, decrease the count of opened_tags
            elif segment == end_tag_b:
                opened_tags -= 1
                result[-1] += end_tag_b

            # If we're inside a tagged section, append the segment to the last opened tag
            elif opened_tags > 0:
                result[-1] += segment

            # Otherwise, simply append the segment to the result array
            else:
                result.append(segment)          
    return result

def remove_empty_lines():
    remove_empty_lines.doc_name  = doc_name
    
    app = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch("Word.Application")
    script_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe())))
    remove_empty_lines.doc_name = doc_name
    file_path = os.path.join(script_dir, remove_empty_lines.doc_name)
    word = win32.Dispatch("Word.Application")

    doc = app.Documents.Open(file_path)

    # Identify and remove empty lines
    # Replace two consecutive paragraph marks with one (converts empty lines to non-empty)
    find = app.Selection.Find
    find.ClearFormatting()
    find.Replacement.ClearFormatting()

    find.Text = "^p^p"
    find.Replacement.Text = "^p"
    find.Execute(Replace=win32.constants.wdReplaceAll)
    
    # Replace two consecutive line breaks with one (converts empty lines to non-empty)
    find.Text = "^l^l"
    find.Replacement.Text = "^l"
    find.Execute(Replace=win32.constants.wdReplaceAll)

    # Save and close the document
    doc.Save()
    doc.Close()

    # Quit the Word application
    app.Quit()


def tag_resolve():
    tag_resolve.doc_name  = doc_name
    doc = docx.Document(tag_resolve.doc_name)

    # doc = docx.Document('sample.docx')

    # Define the starting and end tags
    start_tag_b = '<strong>'
    end_tag_b = '</strong>'
    start_tag_i = '<em>'
    end_tag_i = '</em>'


    tagged_and_non_tagged_texts = []
    column_string = []
    text_i=[]
    empty_list=[]

    for para in doc.paragraphs:
        para_text = para.text
        # print(para_text)
        if para_text == '':
            continue
        if start_tag_b in para_text:
            ### Create a new paragraph 
            newPara = para.insert_paragraph_before(text=None, style=None)
            para.clear()  # Remove the existing so we don't have duplicates

            ### Get a list of indexes for the start/end tag ranges
            indexes = [item for t in zip(
                [s.start() for s in re.finditer(start_tag_b, para_text)],
                [s.start() + len(end_tag_b) for s in re.finditer(end_tag_b, para_text)],
            ) for item in t]
            # print(indexes)
            
            if indexes[0] != 0:
                indexes.insert(0, 0)

            ### Divide the text into bold/not bold sections
            sections = [para_text[i:j] for i, j in zip(indexes, indexes[1:] + [None])]
            # print(sections)
            
            
            for text_i in sections:
                # print(text_i)
                tagged_and_non_tagged_texts = split_tagged_sections(text_i,'<em>','</em>')
                column_string = tagged_and_non_tagged_texts
                for i in range(len(column_string)): 
                    empty_list = [column_string[i]]
                    # print(empty_list)
                    
                    row_array = np.array(empty_list)
                    row_array = str(row_array).strip('[]')
                    row_array = row_array[1:-1]            
                    # print(row_array)  
                    
                    if start_tag_b in row_array:
                        string2bold2 = re.sub('<[^<]+?>', '', row_array)
                        # print(newPara.text)
                        run = newPara.add_run(string2bold2)
                        run.bold = True
                        
                        if(start_tag_i in row_array):
                            run.italic = True
                    
                    elif(start_tag_i in row_array and start_tag_b not in row_array):
                        string2ital = re.sub(start_tag_i, '', row_array)
                        string2ital2 = re.sub(end_tag_i, '', string2ital)
                        run = newPara.add_run(string2ital2)
                        run.italic = True
                        
                    else:
                        newPara.add_run(row_array.replace('\n', ''))
            
    # doc.save('sample_modified.docx')
    doc.save(tag_resolve.doc_name)        
    
    remove_empty_lines()
    
    
doc_name = 'sample1.docx'
# doc_name = ''

def main():
    tag_resolve();
```

After applying this code, the resulting processed text is as follows, given with original text.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/c3SeJ.png